# Array multidimensional javascript com angular está indefinido

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Estou tentando criar um array multidimensional mas ele me retorna **resultados[array.Estado] is undefined**. Estou usando `angularjs`:

resultados = new Array();

```
    var indice = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.filteredDados, function(array, key){

        resultados[array.Estado][indice] = array.Venda;

        indice++;

    });

    angular.forEach(resultados, function (a,b){

        console.log(a+' '+b);
    });
```

Comment: O que tem nesse array `$scope.filteredDados`?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro um jSON

Comment: Eu imagino que sim, mas eu quis dizer quais dados que tem nele?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro são assim: `{"Ano":2016, "Mês": 1, "Estado":"SP", "Cultura": "x", "Segmento":"y", "Venda": "300.00"}`

Comment: Então a minha resposta deve servir para você de uma olhada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160493/57237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, isso não é um array do tipo matriz (array[n][n]), o que você esta fazendo é um objeto que possui um array nas propriedades (object{x:[n]}).
Ex:

```
var i = 0;
var result = null;
[{Estado: "SP", Venda: "200Temers"}].forEach((item) => { result[item.Estado][i] = ; i++; })
// Seu result vai virar isso aqui: 
// result = { SP: [ "200Temers" ] }
```

Ok, depois dessa correção conceitual, vamos continuar. Eu imagino que o resultado que você esta buscando é uma propriedade para cada estado e cada propriedade dessa vai ter um array com as vendas, então:

```
var resultados = {};

$scope.filteredDados.forEach((arrayItem) => {
    resultados[arrayItem.Estado] = resultados[arrayItem.Estado] || [];
    resultados[arrayItem.Estado].push(arrayItem.Venda)
});

for (atributo in resultados) {
    resultados[atributo].forEach((venda) => {
        console.log(atributo + ": " + venda);
    })
}
```